# Spring Boot 406 Not Acceptable on subdirectory

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application. I have 406 Not Acceptable on angular.min.js file if this file is in subdirectory (angular).

**200 OK:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

> /src/main/webapp/js/angular.min.js

**but 406 Not Acceptable:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

> /src/main/webapp/js/angular/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.

I added a REST service with a path that matches was my angularjs src way. :(

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{code}/{width}/{height}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
```

**SOLUTION:** value = "**/api**/{code}/{width}/{height}"